# View in browser not loading current page

Tags: browser, visual-studio-2013, contextmenu

I'm not sure what has changed, but I can no longer (right click -> View in Browser) and it loads the current page.

It loads the root (localhost).

In my web project properties, I have current page selected (see below)

I'm sure it is just a setting I am missing, or something, so I'm asking.
I have already tried to repair the installation also.

I am running Visual Studio 2013 (Update 5) on Windows 10.  Any ideas?

[image: Project Properties]

Comment: I have exactly this issue too. Apart from your post there is not much other reporting of this issue. I also used vs2013. Interesting for other people: I moved this project to vs2015 comm ed. It did NOT solve the issue.
Conclusion: the problem sticks to the project itself. Most likely web.configs or project configuration.